# How to develop these two selectable containers?

Tags: flutter, e-commerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQPuH.jpg)

Please check the above image.
I want to create these two selectable containers that if i i select home container the home container should be selected,and if i select office container, the office container should be selected and the border of selected container should be orange like this in the screen.

I tried it by making a simple container, i can create these statically but i want to make it selectable.

Comment: Hey, show your code .. you will need a StatefulWidget to handle which Container is selected, a GestureDetector or an InkWell to detect the onTap and specific Decorations for the selected border state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a builder. If so, you can take advantage of the index

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
          width: size.width * 0.80,
          child: MaterialButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text(
              "Add Card",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35.0, vertical: 20),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(19),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.adaptive.arrow_back,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 30),
                      const Text(
                        "Shopping Cart (5)",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.black),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
                sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Text(
                    "Delivery Address",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            currentIndex = index;
                          });

                          print(currentIndex);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: currentIndex == index
                                    ? const Color(0xFFFFB024)
                                    : Colors.grey,
                              )),
                          height: 100,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Item $index",
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                  currentIndex == index
                                      ? Container(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                              color: const Color(0xFFFFB024)),
                                          child: const Icon(
                                            Icons.check,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ))
                                      : Container()
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  const Text("An address"),
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      child: const Text("Edit"))
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  // 40 list items
                  childCount: 2,
                ),
              ),
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
                sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: DottedBorder(
                  borderType: BorderType.RRect,
                  dashPattern: const [15],
                  strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
                  strokeWidth: 2,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  radius: const Radius.circular(12),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  child: const ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.add_circle_outline_sharp,
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Text("Add New Address")
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

result: [image]

Answer (score 0):

**TextFormField** has a property for setting the style when the input is Focused

```
 TextFormField{ 
  // ... other properties
  focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.orange, width: 2.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a value notifier or an attribute to store selected container value and update UI on change.

If you use `ValueNotifier` you can wrap the `Column` that contains both containers with `ValueListenableBuilder` and add border based on selected value.

If you have an attribute, you need to setState() on updating selected index.

You can store the index of selection and show border if

```
indexOfContainer==selected
```